# how to end call button two peers in android using webrtc

Tags: android, webrtc

Hi in the below code how to end call between two peers from mobile to mobile.How to implement event handler functions in android.I have customized my layout for that I have image button to end the call. when click on end image want to end the call and if any one want to turn on back or front camera it should work and mute the audio unmute audio .

Can any one help me on this part

```
public class VideocallFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "VideocallFragment";
    private static final int RC_CALL = 111;
    private Socket socket;
    private boolean isInitiator;
    private ImageButton button_call_disconnect;
    public static final int VIDEO_RESOLUTION_WIDTH = 1280;
    private boolean isStarted;
    private boolean isChannelReady;
    private PeerConnectionFactory factory;
    private PeerConnection peerConnection;
    private EglBase rootEglBase;
    AudioSource audioSource;
    public static final int FPS = 30;
    public static final String VIDEO_TRACK_ID = "ARDAMSv0";
    AudioTrack localAudioTrack;
    MediaConstraints audioConstraints;
    private VideoTrack videoTrackFromCamera;
    private SurfaceViewRenderer surfaceView,surfaceView2;
    public static final int VIDEO_RESOLUTION_HEIGHT = 720;


    public VideocallFragment() {
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_main, container, false);
        surfaceView=rootView.findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        surfaceView2=rootView.findViewById(R.id.surfaceView2);
        button_call_disconnect=rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_call_disconnect);
        start();
        button_call_disconnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (socket != null) {
            sendMessage("bye");
            socket.disconnect();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @AfterPermissionGranted(RC_CALL)
    private void start() {
        String[] perms = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO};
        if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(getContext(), perms)) {
            connectToSignallingServer();

            initializeSurfaceViews();

            initializePeerConnectionFactory();

            createVideoTrackFromCameraAndShowIt();

            initializePeerConnections();

            startStreamingVideo();
        } else {
            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, "Need some permissions", RC_CALL, perms);
        }
    }

    private void connectToSignallingServer() {
        try {
            socket = IO.socket("http://192.168.0.102:3000");

            socket.on(EVENT_CONNECT, args -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "connectToSignallingServer: connect");
                socket.emit("create or join", "chandra");
            }).on("ipaddr", args -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "connectToSignallingServer: ipaddr");
            }).on("created", args -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "connectToSignallingServer: created");
                isInitiator = true;
            }).on("full", args -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "connectToSignallingServer: full");
            }).on("join", args -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "connectToSignallingServer: join");
                Log.d(TAG, "connectToSignallingServer: Another peer made a request to join room");
                Log.d(TAG, "connectToSignallingServer: This peer is the initiator of room");
                isChannelReady = true;
            }).on("joined", args -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "connectToSignallingServer: joined");
                isChannelReady = true;
            }).on("log", args -> {
                for (Object arg : args) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "connectToSignallingServer: " + String.valueOf(arg));
                }
            }).on("message", args -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "connectToSignallingServer: got a message");
            }).on("message", args -> {
                try {
                    if (args[0] instanceof String) {
                        String message = (String) args[0];
                        if (message.equals("got user media")) {
                            maybeStart();
                        }
                    } else {
                        JSONObject message = (JSONObject) args[0];
                        Log.d(TAG, "connectToSignallingServer: got message " + message);
                        if (message.getString("type").equals("offer")) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "connectToSignallingServer: received an offer " + isInitiator + " " + isStarted);
                            if (!isInitiator && !isStarted) {
                                maybeStart();
                            }
                            peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new SimpleSdpObserver(), new SessionDescription(OFFER, message.getString("sdp")));
                            doAnswer();
                        } else if (message.getString("type").equals("answer") && isStarted) {
                            peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new SimpleSdpObserver(), new SessionDescription(ANSWER, message.getString("sdp")));
                        } else if (message.getString("type").equals("candidate") && isStarted) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "connectToSignallingServer: receiving candidates");
                            IceCandidate candidate = new IceCandidate(message.getString("id"), message.getInt("label"), message.getString("candidate"));
                            peerConnection.addIceCandidate(candidate);
                        }
                        /*else if (message === 'bye' && isStarted) {
                        handleRemoteHangup();
                    }*/
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }).on(EVENT_DISCONNECT, args -> {

                Log.d(TAG, "connectToSignallingServer: disconnect");
            });
            socket.connect();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //MirtDPM4
    private void doAnswer() {
        peerConnection.createAnswer(new SimpleSdpObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onCreateSuccess(SessionDescription sessionDescription) {
                peerConnection.setLocalDescription(new SimpleSdpObserver(), sessionDescription);
                JSONObject message = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    message.put("type", "answer");
                    message.put("sdp", sessionDescription.description);
                    sendMessage(message);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new MediaConstraints());
    }

    private void maybeStart() {
        Log.d(TAG, "maybeStart: " + isStarted + " " + isChannelReady);
        if (!isStarted && isChannelReady) {
            isStarted = true;
            if (isInitiator) {
                doCall();
            }
        }
    }

    private void doCall() {
        MediaConstraints sdpMediaConstraints = new MediaConstraints();

        sdpMediaConstraints.mandatory.add(
                new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveAudio", "true"));
        sdpMediaConstraints.mandatory.add(
                new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveVideo", "true"));
        peerConnection.createOffer(new SimpleSdpObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onCreateSuccess(SessionDescription sessionDescription) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCreateSuccess: ");
                peerConnection.setLocalDescription(new SimpleSdpObserver(), sessionDescription);
                JSONObject message = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    message.put("type", "offer");
                    message.put("sdp", sessionDescription.description);
                    sendMessage(message);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, sdpMediaConstraints);
    }

    private void sendMessage(Object message) {
        socket.emit("message", message);
    }

    private void initializeSurfaceViews() {
        rootEglBase = EglBase.create();
        surfaceView.init(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext(), null);
        surfaceView.setEnableHardwareScaler(true);
        surfaceView.setMirror(true);

       surfaceView2.init(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext(), null);
       surfaceView2.setEnableHardwareScaler(true);
       surfaceView2.setMirror(true);

        //add one more
    }

    private void initializePeerConnectionFactory() {
        PeerConnectionFactory.initializeAndroidGlobals(getActivity(), true, true, true);
        factory = new PeerConnectionFactory(null);
        factory.setVideoHwAccelerationOptions(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext(), rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext());
    }

    private void createVideoTrackFromCameraAndShowIt() {
        audioConstraints = new MediaConstraints();
        VideoCapturer videoCapturer = createVideoCapturer();
        VideoSource videoSource = factory.createVideoSource(videoCapturer);
        videoCapturer.startCapture(VIDEO_RESOLUTION_WIDTH, VIDEO_RESOLUTION_HEIGHT, FPS);

        videoTrackFromCamera = factory.createVideoTrack(VIDEO_TRACK_ID, videoSource);
        videoTrackFromCamera.setEnabled(true);
        videoTrackFromCamera.addRenderer(new VideoRenderer(surfaceView2));

        //create an AudioSource instance
        audioSource = factory.createAudioSource(audioConstraints);
        localAudioTrack = factory.createAudioTrack("101", audioSource);

    }

    private void initializePeerConnections() {
        peerConnection = createPeerConnection(factory);
    }

    private void startStreamingVideo() {
        MediaStream mediaStream = factory.createLocalMediaStream("ARDAMS");
        mediaStream.addTrack(videoTrackFromCamera);
        mediaStream.addTrack(localAudioTrack);
        peerConnection.addStream(mediaStream);

        sendMessage("got user media");
    }

    private PeerConnection createPeerConnection(PeerConnectionFactory factory) {
        ArrayList<PeerConnection.IceServer> iceServers = new ArrayList<>();
        iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"));

        PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration rtcConfig = new PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration(iceServers);
        MediaConstraints pcConstraints = new MediaConstraints();

        PeerConnection.Observer pcObserver = new PeerConnection.Observer() {
            @Override
            public void onSignalingChange(PeerConnection.SignalingState signalingState) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onSignalingChange: ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onIceConnectionChange(PeerConnection.IceConnectionState iceConnectionState) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onIceConnectionChange: ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onIceConnectionReceivingChange(boolean b) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onIceConnectionReceivingChange: ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onIceGatheringChange(PeerConnection.IceGatheringState iceGatheringState) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onIceGatheringChange: ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onIceCandidate(IceCandidate iceCandidate) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onIceCandidate: ");
                JSONObject message = new JSONObject();

                try {
                    message.put("type", "candidate");
                    message.put("label", iceCandidate.sdpMLineIndex);
                    message.put("id", iceCandidate.sdpMid);
                    message.put("candidate", iceCandidate.sdp);

                    Log.d(TAG, "onIceCandidate: sending candidate " + message);
                    sendMessage(message);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onIceCandidatesRemoved(IceCandidate[] iceCandidates) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onIceCandidatesRemoved: ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAddStream(MediaStream mediaStream) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onAddStream: " + mediaStream.videoTracks.size());
                VideoTrack remoteVideoTrack = mediaStream.videoTracks.get(0);
                AudioTrack remoteAudioTrack = mediaStream.audioTracks.get(0);
                remoteAudioTrack.setEnabled(true);
                remoteVideoTrack.setEnabled(true);
                remoteVideoTrack.addRenderer(new VideoRenderer(surfaceView));

            }

            @Override
            public void onRemoveStream(MediaStream mediaStream) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onRemoveStream: ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onDataChannel(DataChannel dataChannel) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChannel: ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onRenegotiationNeeded() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onRenegotiationNeeded: ");
            }
        };

        return factory.createPeerConnection(rtcConfig, pcConstraints, pcObserver);
    }

    private VideoCapturer createVideoCapturer() {
        VideoCapturer videoCapturer;
        if (useCamera2()) {
            videoCapturer = createCameraCapturer(new Camera2Enumerator(getContext()));
        } else {
            videoCapturer = createCameraCapturer(new Camera1Enumerator(true));
        }
        return videoCapturer;
    }

    private VideoCapturer createCameraCapturer(CameraEnumerator enumerator) {
        final String[] deviceNames = enumerator.getDeviceNames();

        for (String deviceName : deviceNames) {
            if (enumerator.isFrontFacing(deviceName)) {
                VideoCapturer videoCapturer = enumerator.createCapturer(deviceName, null);

                if (videoCapturer != null) {
                    return videoCapturer;
                }
            }
        }

        for (String deviceName : deviceNames) {
            if (!enumerator.isFrontFacing(deviceName)) {
                VideoCapturer videoCapturer = enumerator.createCapturer(deviceName, null);

                if (videoCapturer != null) {
                    return videoCapturer;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    private boolean useCamera2() {
        return Camera2Enumerator.isSupported(getContext());
    }


}
```

Comment: Using socket channel between two peers will do the job for you. make sure when the end button pressed, the signal is received on the other peer side and destroy your connection on both sides

Comment: @MoeinDeveloper I tried socket.disconnect() but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but maybe useful for the others.
You can call `close();` on the RTCPeerConnection but there is a limitation, it will not close the call on the other side if the call receiver calls it first.
You can use the `onconnectionstatechange` event and call `close()` if the other part ended the call

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/build_a_phone_with_peerjs/connect_peers/End_a_call